# What configuration setting(s) and/or logic am I missing for Vue compatibility in VS Code extension application using rollup.js?

Tags: vue.js, vscode-extensions, rollupjs

I'm currently trying to render a single Vue component (`App.vue` boilerplate) in my VS Code Extension application and getting this error in the debug console of the Extension Development Host window:

```
app.js:23 Uncaught ReferenceError: Vue is not defined
    at app.js:23
```

`app.js` is the compiled and bundled output using Rollup.js so here is my `rollup.config.js`:

```
import path from 'path';
import fs from 'fs';

import alias from '@rollup/plugin-alias';
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import esbuild from 'rollup-plugin-esbuild';
import filesize from 'rollup-plugin-filesize';
import image from '@rollup/plugin-image';
import json from '@rollup/plugin-json';
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss';
import postcssImport from 'postcss-import';
import replace from '@rollup/plugin-replace';
import { nodeResolve } from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import requireContext from 'rollup-plugin-require-context';
import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser';
import vuePlugin from 'rollup-plugin-vue';
import globals from 'rollup-plugin-node-globals';
import builtins from 'rollup-plugin-node-builtins';
import autoExternal from 'rollup-plugin-auto-external';

const production = !process.env.ROLLUP_WATCH;

const postCssPlugins = [
  postcssImport(),
];

export default fs
  .readdirSync(path.join(__dirname, 'web', 'pages'))
  .map((input) => {
    const name = input.split('.')[0].toLowerCase();
    return {
      input: `web/pages/${input}`,
      output: {
        file: `out/compiled/${name}.js`,
        format: 'iife',
        name: 'app',
        sourcemap: false,
        globals: {
          'vue': 'Vue'
        }
      },
      plugins: [
        nodeResolve({
          jsnext: true,
          main: true,
          browser: true,
          extensions: ['.mjs', '.js', '.jsx', '.json', '.ts'],
          preferBuiltins: false,
          dedupe: ['vue']
        }),
        autoExternal(),
        vuePlugin({
          css: false
        }),
        commonjs(),
        globals(),
        builtins(),
        json(),
        alias({
          entries: [{
            find: '@',
            replacement: __dirname + '/src/'
          }],
        }),
        image(),
        postcss({
          extract: `${name}.css`,
          plugins: postCssPlugins,
        }),
        requireContext(),
        replace({
          'process.env.NODE_ENV': production ?
            '"production"' : '"development"',
          preventAssignment: true,
        }),
        esbuild({
          minify: production,
          target: 'es2015',
        }),
        production && terser(),
        production && filesize(),
      ],
      watch: {
        clearScreen: false,
        exclude: ['node_modules/**'],
      },
    };
  });
```

My `package.json` includes the dependency for Vue but the error persists. When I look into the compiled `app.js`, I can see that Vue is recognized as a `class` rather than `any`--making the assumption that Vue is readable and thus expecting my `App.vue`(mounted through an `App.js` file in a separate folder on the root directory) to render in the sidebar panel.

I'm currently using Vue v3 syntax and it seemed to make no difference when I tried the v2 syntax to try and mount my component in `App.js`:

```
// v3
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "@/webviews/src/App.vue";

createApp(App).mount("#app");


// v2
// import Vue from "vue";
// import App from "@/webviews/src/App.vue";

// new Vue({ render: h => h(App) }).$mount("#app");
```

As for VS Code extension boilerplate, my `extension.ts` has the sidebar registered as a webview:

```
context.subscriptions.push(
    vscode.window.registerWebviewViewProvider("mv-sidebar", sidebarProvider)
);
```

`SidebarProvider.ts`:

```
import * as vscode from "vscode";
import { getNonce } from "./getNonce";

export class SidebarProvider implements vscode.WebviewViewProvider {
  // public static readonly viewType = 'mv-sidebar';

  _view?: vscode.WebviewView;

  constructor(private readonly _extensionUri: vscode.Uri) {}

  public resolveWebviewView(webviewView: vscode.WebviewView) {
    this._view = webviewView;

    webviewView.webview.options = {
      enableScripts: true,

      localResourceRoots: [
        this._extensionUri
      ],
    };

    webviewView.webview.html = this._getHtmlForWebview(webviewView.webview);
  }

  public revive(panel: vscode.WebviewView) {
    this._view = panel;
  }

  private _getHtmlForWebview(webview: vscode.Webview) {
    const styleResetUri = webview.asWebviewUri(
      vscode.Uri.joinPath(
        this._extensionUri, "media", "reset.css")
    );

    const styleVSCodeUri = webview.asWebviewUri(
      vscode.Uri.joinPath(
        this._extensionUri, "media", "vscode.css")
    );

    const styleMainUri = webview.asWebviewUri(
      vscode.Uri.joinPath(
        this._extensionUri, "out", "compiled/app.css")
    );

    const scriptUri = webview.asWebviewUri(
      vscode.Uri.joinPath(
        this._extensionUri, "out", "compiled/app.js")
    );

    const nonce = getNonce();

    return `
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link href="${styleResetUri}" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="${styleVSCodeUri}" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="${styleMainUri}" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>Web Pages Panel</title>
        <script nonce="${nonce}">
            const vscode = acquireVsCodeApi();
        </script>
      </head>
        <body>
          <div id="app"></div>
          <script src="${scriptUri}" nonce="${nonce}">
        </body>
      </html>
    `;
  }
}
```

Excuse the large post (needed to detail as much as I could)--given the information provided, what could I add and/or subtract?

Thanks!

Comment: `'vue': 'Vue'` means that there is supposed to be Vue global variable. You didn't define it. Why is it there at all?

Comment: @EstusFlask I was getting a `(!) Missing global variable name` warning during compilation suggesting Vue was missing--am I supposed to import the Vue module on the rollup.config.js as well?

Comment: What exactly did you try when you got this? No, you shouldn't import Vue in config, it's of no use there. You need to import Vue everywhere you use it and not have `globals` in config.